# Inno Setup - How to change a label caption [or other controls in general], when selected value in combox box changes

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

When changing a language in combo box (without clicking ok), I want to change texts of the dialog (label, form caption, button caption)

```pascal
procedure SelectLanguage();
var
  LanguageForm: TSetupForm;
  CancelButton: TNewButton;
  OKButton: TNewButton;
  LangCombo: TNewComboBox;
  SelectLabel: TNewStaticText;
  Languages: TStrings;
  Params: string;
  Instance: THandle;
  P, I: Integer;
  S, L: string;
begin
  Languages := TStringList.Create();

  Languages.Add('en=English');
  Languages.Add('cs='+#$010C+'e'+#$0161+'tina');

  LanguageForm := CreateCustomForm;

  LanguageForm.Caption := SetupMessage(msgSelectLanguageTitle);
  LanguageForm.ClientWidth := ScaleX(297);
  LanguageForm.ClientHeight := ScaleY(125);
  LanguageForm.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
  LanguageForm.Center;

  CancelButton := TNewButton.Create(LanguageForm);
  CancelButton.Parent := LanguageForm;
  CancelButton.Left := ScaleX(214);
  CancelButton.Top := ScaleY(93);
  CancelButton.Width := ScaleY(75);
  CancelButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
  CancelButton.TabOrder := 3;
  CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel;
  CancelButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonCancel);

  OKButton := TNewButton.Create(LanguageForm);
  OKButton.Parent := LanguageForm;
  OKButton.Left := ScaleX(133);
  OKButton.Top := ScaleY(93);
  OKButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
  OKButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
  OKButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonOK);
  OKButton.Default := True
  OKButton.ModalResult := mrOK;
  OKButton.TabOrder := 2;

  LangCombo := TNewComboBox.Create(LanguageForm);
  LangCombo.Parent := LanguageForm;
  LangCombo.Left := ScaleX(16);
  LangCombo.Top := ScaleY(56);
  LangCombo.Width := ScaleX(273);
  LangCombo.Height := ScaleY(21);
  LangCombo.Style := csDropDownList;
  LangCombo.DropDownCount := 16;
  LangCombo.TabOrder := 1;

  SelectLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(LanguageForm);
  SelectLabel.Parent := LanguageForm;
  SelectLabel.Left := ScaleX(16);
  SelectLabel.Top := ScaleY(8);
  SelectLabel.Width := ScaleX(273);
  SelectLabel.Height := ScaleY(39);
  SelectLabel.AutoSize := False
  SelectLabel.Caption := SetupMessage(msgSelectLanguageLabel);
  SelectLabel.TabOrder := 0;
  SelectLabel.WordWrap := True;

  for I := 0 to Languages.Count - 1 do
  begin
    P := Pos('=', Languages.Strings[I]);
    L := Copy(Languages.Strings[I], 0, P - 1);
    S := Copy(Languages.Strings[I], P + 1, Length(Languages.Strings[I]) - P);
    LangCombo.Items.Add(S);
    if L = ActiveLanguage then
      LangCombo.ItemIndex := I;
  end;

  if LanguageForm.ShowModal = mrOK then
  begin
    { ... }
  end;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  SelectLanguage();
  { ... }
end;
```

[image: Spanish first language]

Spanish: first language.

[image: I select english and no change the language of the language selector]

I select English and no change the language of the language selector.

Comment: You change it by setting the item index (see the code that Martin gave you in your earlier question). You don't change the language without clicking OK. The OK button means you want to use the language you selected - it's not appropriate to just change the language without the user's consent. Also, when asking a follow up question related to the earlier one, have the courtesy to say so and to link to the previous one so that people have an idea what you're referencing when you ask. Giving that link gives people context so they don't answer a totally different question (as happened here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the code already. You just need to make some local variables in the `SelectLanguage` function global, so they can be used in the `LangChange` function:

```pascal
var
  LanguageForm: TSetupForm;
  SelectLabel: TNewStaticText;
  CancelButton: TNewButton;

procedure LangChange(Sender : TObject);
begin
  case TNewComboBox(Sender).ItemIndex of
    0: { English }
      begin
        SelectLabel.Caption := 'Select the language to use during the installation:';
        CancelButton.Caption := 'Cancel';
        LanguageForm.Caption := 'Select setup language';
      end;
    1: { Czech }
      begin
        SelectLabel.Caption := 'Zvolte jazyk, kter'+#$FD+' se m'+#$E1+' pou'+#$17E+#$ED+'t b'+#$11B+'hem instalace:';
        CancelButton.Caption := 'Storno';
        LanguageForm.Caption := 'V'+#$FD+'b'+#$11B+'r jazyka pr'+#$16F+'vodce instalac'+#$ED+'';
      end;
  end;
end;
```

---

In the `SelectLanguage`, remove these the declarations of local variables:

```pascal
  LanguageForm: TSetupForm;
  SelectLabel: TNewStaticText;
  CancelButton: TNewButton;
```

And assign the `LangChange` event handler:

```pascal
  LangCombo.OnChange := @LangChange;
```

---

[image: English]

[image: Czech]